# update a field based on null results on table join

Tags: t-sql

I keep finding references on how to do get the SET value from another table, but we dont really use this field so am happy to set it to a generic value '1'

I just want to set the 11k examples where the Model type has been deleted using the select at the bottom of this query.

```
update webhelpdesk.dbo.ASSET
set MODEL_ID = N'1'
where ASSET_NUMBER = 
    (select a1.ASSET_NUMBER
    from asset a1
    left join webhelpdesk.dbo.MODEL m1 on m1.MODEL_ID=a1.MODEL_ID
    where m1.MODEL_ID is null)
```

this returns 
**Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.**

I guess I should use something else rather than update
Help please

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use `IN` instead of `=` in WHERE condition

```
update webhelpdesk.dbo.ASSET
set MODEL_ID = N'1'
where ASSET_NUMBER IN
    (select a1.ASSET_NUMBER
    from asset a1
    left join webhelpdesk.dbo.MODEL m1 on m1.MODEL_ID=a1.MODEL_ID
    where m1.MODEL_ID is null)
```